# Issue with column sizes using TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have the following code:

```
        var tlp = new TableLayoutPanel
                      {
                          Location = new Point(0, 0),
                          Name = "TableLayoutPanel1",
                          Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                          BackColor = Color.White,
                          TabIndex = 0
                      };

        Controls.Add(tlp);

        tlp.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 14f));
        tlp.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 18f));
        tlp.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 12f));
        tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 100f));
        tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute,  50f));

        var label3 = new Label
        {
            Font = new Font("Tahoma", 8, FontStyle.Regular),
            Text = Description,
            AutoSize = false,
            Width=50,
            ForeColor = Color.Black,
            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopLeft
        };
        tlp.Controls.Add(label3, 1, 2);
```

My problem is, when I run my application, there is nothing displayed. If I change the last line to display in the first column, like so:

```
        tlp.Controls.Add(label3, 0, 2);
```

Then it shows up just fine in the first column. Also, if I change my `ColumnStyle` definition to `SizeType.Percentage` instead of `Absolute`, that works fine too, but I don't want a percentage, I want a 100 pixel fixed column on the left and a 50 pixel fixed column on the right.

Can someone point me into the right direction on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to also set the RowCount and ColumnCount properties.  Strange, I know.

So:

```
tlp.RowCount = 3;
tlp.ColumnCount = 2;
```

Comment: Wow that was my problem. Can't believe you have to set this seeing as how it should be able to figure it out by however many rows or columns I actually add.

Comment: Yeah, you would think it would work just by adding to the collection.  Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a long time to figure this out:

add Columnstyles and Rowstyles is not enough, you have to set ColumnCount and RowCount as well, as explained above. But...

Setting RowCount and ColumnCount is not enough either! You need to add Columnstyles and Rowstyles as well.

I think I finally got this component figured out...

Bas